# Can some one please explain the below python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Car: pass

c1 = Car()
c2 = Car()

attr = "price"
value = 20000

for obj in c1,c2 : setattr(obj, attr, value)
```

This sets the "price" attribute to `c1` and `c1` instances.

But how does the `for` loop work with obj?

Comment: You mean the `for obj in c1, c2:` part? That's just a loop over a tuple.

Comment: `c1,c2` is a tuple, your code is equivalent to `for obj in (c1, c2): ...`.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Got it ... Thnx :)  Now am realizin how siilly the question was ;)

Answer (score 0):

Python tuples are formed by the *comma*:

```
>>> class Car: pass
...
>>> c1 = Car()
>>> c2 = Car()
>>> c1, c2
(<__main__.Car instance at 0x1031fa368>, <__main__.Car instance at 0x1031fa290>)
>>> type(_)  # type of the last result
<type 'tuple'>
```

Parentheses are *optional* here; you could also write the tuple as `(c1, c2)`.

The `for` loop simply iterates over that tuple; the loop assigns each element in the tuple to `obj` for that iteration:

```
>>> for obj in c1, c2: print obj
...
<__main__.Car instance at 0x1031fa368>
<__main__.Car instance at 0x1031fa290>
```

`obj` is thus first bound to the `Car` instance `c1` references, then to the one `c2` references.

The loop thus simply does this: `obj = c1`, then `obj = c2`, and executes the loop body after each such assignment. The `setattr()` call simply then sets the attribute named in the `attr` string to the value found in `value`.

Comment: "Python tuples are formed by the _comma_". There is one exception to that: `type(())` gives me `<class 'tuple'>` (at least in Python 3.4).

Comment: @Matthias: that's because the only way to express an empty tuple is by using parentheses. Parentheses are also required to disambiguate the use of a comma for a tuple vs. something else, like in a function call. So you need to use parentheses for `type((c1, c2))` as well, because `type(c1, c2)` passes in two arguments, not one tuple.

Comment: @Matthias: but on it's own, `1,` is a tuple with one element, while plain `1` is just an integer.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between `1` and `1,`. It's just that I explained this "comma thing" some days ago to another user in a Python forum and was confronted with this example. Since then I wondered about this ...

Comment: @Matthias: see [*Parenthesized forms*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms) for the motivation there.

Answer (score -1):

```
Class Car: pass
```

Is an empty class declaration, similar to, say, a struct in C., then:

```
c1 = Car()
c2 = Car()
```

two instances of Car, uninitialized, then,

```
attr = "price"
value = 20000
```

two variables, and finally,

```
for obj in c1, c2 : setattr(obj, attr, value)
```

iterate over them with a "helper" object, which you use to set attributes to the values in the variables to both instances.

Comment: `obj` isn't some kind of separate  "helper" object - it's just a name that is bound in turn to the objects that are also bound to the names `c1` and `c2`. For more info on this topic, please see the article I linked to in my comment on the question.